# flask-sqlalchemy circular import issue with query

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I'm starting to build a Flask app that right now has one form and one model.
I have `app.py`, `models.py`, `views.py` and `form.py`. I have tried many different variations and the following is the most straight-forward close-to-working version I can arrive at. But I still run into either a circular import problem or a "Flask app isn't registered with SQLAlchemy instance" problem. I am not outright declaring a new SQLAlchemy instance, it seems like I'm registering the app with SQLAlchemy in my app.py. I've tried adding a `db.create_all()` snippet of code and doesn't seem to have any effect. Can anyone point out where am I going wrong please?

My app.py

```
import views.views as views

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('app_config.DevConfig')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# with app.app_context():
#    db.create_all()

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=views.index_func)
app.add_url_rule('/index', view_func=views.index_func)
app.add_url_rule('/download', view_func=views.download_func, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

My models.py:

```
from app import db

class ShelfTable(db.Model):
    __tablename__  = "group_shelves"
    shelf_label = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    download_name = db.Column(db.String)
    url = db.Column(db.String)
    page_size = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
    sort_order = db.Column(db.String, nullable=True)
```

views.py:

```
from downloader.form import DownloadForm
### import ShelfTable here results in a circular import
# from models import ShelfTable 

def download_func():
    ### import ShelfTable here results in a registration error
    from models import ShelfTable
    labels = ShelfTable.query.with_entities(ShelfTable.shelf_label).all()
    # Populate the SelectField choices
    options_form = DownloadForm(request.form)
    choice_values = [(label[0], label[0]) for label in labels]
    options_form.shelf_choice.choices = choice_values
    options_form.shelf_choice.default = choice_values[0]
```

The registration error

```
download_func
    labels = ShelfTable.query.with_entities(ShelfTable.shelf_label).all()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2673, in all
    return self._iter().all()  # type: ignore
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 2827, in _iter
    result: Union[ScalarResult[_T], Result[_T]] = self.session.execute(
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2306, in execute
    return self._execute_internal(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py", line 2179, in _execute_internal
    bind = self.get_bind(**bind_arguments)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\session.py", line 53, in get_bind
    engines = self._db.engines
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "...\venv\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\extension.py", line 690, in engines
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: The current Flask app is not registered with this 'SQLAlchemy' instance. Did you forget to call 'init_app', or did you create multiple 'SQLAlchemy' instances?
```